# Hibernate cascade anotation

Tags: java, hibernate, cascade

I have such class which describe the Employee, with manager and subordinates

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;

private String name;

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Employee manager;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<Employee> workers;
```

and when I want to remove manager or subordinate I get

```
    com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`companu`.`employee`, CONSTRAINT `FKou6wbxug1d0qf9mabut3xqblo` FOREIGN KEY (`manager_id`) REFERENCES `employee` (`id`))
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.42.jar:5.1.42]
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.42.jar:5.1.42]
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:935) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.42.jar:5.1.42]
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3973) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.42.jar:5.1.42]
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3909) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.42.jar:5.1.42]
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2527) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.42.jar:5.1.42]
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2680) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.42.jar:5.1.42]
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2490) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.42.jar:5.1.42]
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1858) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.42.jar:5.1.42]
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2079) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.42.jar:5.1.42]
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2013) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.42.jar:5.1.42]
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:5104) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.42.jar:5.1.42]
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1998) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.42.jar:5.1.42]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.StatementFacade$StatementProxy.invoke(StatementFacade.java:114) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.15.jar:na]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy107.executeUpdate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:204) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:45) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.delete(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3261) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.delete(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3498) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityDeleteAction.execute(EntityDeleteAction.java:98) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:582) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:456) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:337) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1282) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:465) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2963) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2339) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:485) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:147) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$100(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:38) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:231) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:65) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:61) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:517) ~[spring-orm-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:761) ~[spring-tx-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:730) ~[spring-tx-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:504) ~[spring-tx-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:292) ~[spring-tx-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136) ~[spring-tx-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:57) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) ~[spring-aop-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy89.delete(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55) ~[spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:110) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:106) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_121]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_121]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_121]}
```

I read a lot of variants when parent and child its different entity, but when its the same I can't find good solution.

Comment: Delete how? Delete the database record or just setting the field to null?

Comment: db record. When i delete manager then all employees with this manager set null

Comment: It doesn't work this way. You first need to set to null the manager field from his/her employees and only them delete the manager.

Comment: I know it but I supouse that I can use anotation like ` @Cascade(value = org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DETACH)` and hibernate do it by itself

Comment: Detach means changes to the objects are not saved to database. They are independent.